# Dao Test for Dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard

Trying to write Dao Test cases for Dropwizard application.
I have implemented my own version to AbstractDaoTest class which has nothing todo with Dropwizard's configuration. Wondering if I can use Dropwizard's hibernate configuration and get session factory from Dropwizard's HibernateBundle.

```
public AbstractDaoTest() {
            Configuration config=new Configuration();
            config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/testme");
            config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","haha");
            config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password","haha");
            config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            config.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class","thread");
            config.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true"); 
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
```

Is there a way I can get hold of `HibernateBundle` of Dropwizard in my AbstarctDaoTest class?